# React-native 0.61.5 release build android crashed after navigation on a specific route

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

React-native 0.61.5 android release APK is being crashed every time, when I try to navigate to a specific screen. It is working fine on debug mode (`react-native run-android`) but after building release signed APK the crash occurs.
I've tried many stack overflow answers and suggestions but still unable to resolve the issue.

Here is my ADB logcat -

```
01-25 12:12:00.006   852   852 D KeyguardClockSwitch: Updating clock: 1212
01-25 12:12:07.029   583   932 I system_server: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
01-25 12:12:07.030 27970 28043 W audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 78493105 , only wrote 78493089
01-25 12:12:07.208 17214 17247 E ReactNativeJS: Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
01-25 12:12:07.208 17214 17247 E ReactNativeJS: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
01-25 12:12:07.208 17214 17247 E ReactNativeJS: 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
01-25 12:12:07.208 17214 17247 E ReactNativeJS: 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
01-25 12:12:07.208 17214 17247 E ReactNativeJS: See react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
01-25 12:12:07.208 17214 17247 E ReactNativeJS:
01-25 12:12:07.208 17214 17247 E ReactNativeJS: This error is located at:
01-25 12:12:07.216 17214 17247 E ReactNativeJS: Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
01-25 12:12:07.216 17214 17247 E ReactNativeJS: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
01-25 12:12:07.216 17214 17247 E ReactNativeJS: 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
01-25 12:12:07.216 17214 17247 E ReactNativeJS: 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
01-25 12:12:07.216 17214 17247 E ReactNativeJS: See react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
01-25 12:12:07.216 17214 17247 E ReactNativeJS:
01-25 12:12:07.216 17214 17247 E ReactNativeJS: This error is located at:
01-25 12:12:07.244   583   932 I system_server: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: See react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative:
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: This error is located at:
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative:     in x, js engine: hermes, stack:
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: Dr (address at@1:140912
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: useState (address at@1:74995
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: anonymous (address at@1:518750
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: anonymous (address at@1:2282783
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: Ii (address at@1:149619
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: jl (address at@1:164534
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: anonymous@-1
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: an (address at@1:130901
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: Ol (address at@1:164362
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: anonymous (address at@1:162086
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: W (address at@1:242129
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: G (address at@1:242741
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: f (address at@1:243091
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: apply@-1
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: anonymous (address at@1:194742
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: y (address at@1:194024
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: callTimers (address at@1:195796
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: apply@-1
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: value (address at@1:87243
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: anonymous (address at@1:85664
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: value (address at@1:86840
01-25 12:12:07.253 17214 17248 E unknown:ReactNative: value (address at@1:85622
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.revolerlife, PID: 17214
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: See react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime:
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: This error is located at:
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime:     in x, js engine: hermes, stack:
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: Dr (address at@1:140912
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: useState (address at@1:74995
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: anonymous (address at@1:518750
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: anonymous (address at@1:2282783
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: Ii (address at@1:149619
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: jl (address at@1:164534
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: anonymous@-1
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: an (address at@1:130901
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: Ol (address at@1:164362
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: anonymous (address at@1:162086
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: W (address at@1:242129
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: G (address at@1:242741
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: f (address at@1:243091
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: apply@-1
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: anonymous (address at@1:194742
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: y (address at@1:194024
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: callTimers (address at@1:195796
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: apply@-1
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: value (address at@1:87243
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: anonymous (address at@1:85664
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: value (address at@1:86840
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime: value (address at@1:85622
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime:
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:71)
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:371)
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:150)
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:26)
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:225)
01-25 12:12:07.266 17214 17248 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
01-25 12:12:07.279   583  1912 W ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.revolerlife/.MainActivity
01-25 12:12:07.281   583 17321 I DropBoxManagerService: add tag=data_app_crash isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
01-25 12:12:07.286   367   433 D goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x5b2000
01-25 12:12:07.287   367   433 D goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3f903c000 size 0x5b3000
01-25 12:12:07.340   583   632 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
01-25 12:12:07.340   583   632 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
01-25 12:12:07.350 17214 17248 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 17214 SIG: 9
01-25 12:12:07.357   583  5496 D HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae7cb830, tid 5496
01-25 12:12:07.363   583  5496 D HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2
01-25 12:12:07.365   583  5496 W OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
01-25 12:12:07.368   583  5496 D EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xaee133a0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
01-25 12:12:07.384   583   625 I DropBoxManagerService: add tag=system_app_strictmode isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
01-25 12:12:07.394   583  5496 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaee133a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb1dcb270) (first time)
01-25 12:12:07.404   583  1904 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{e7ad92a u0 com.revolerlife/com.revolerlife.MainActivity}
01-25 12:12:07.404   583  1904 W InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'e7ad92a com.revolerlife/com.revolerlife.MainActivity (server)'
01-25 12:12:07.404   350   350 I Zygote  : Process 17214 exited due to signal 9 (Killed)
01-25 12:12:07.408   583  1904 W WindowManager: Failed to deliver inset state change to w=Window{e7ad92a u0 com.revolerlife/com.revolerlife.MainActivity}
01-25 12:12:07.408   583  1904 W WindowManager: android.os.DeadObjectException
01-25 12:12:07.408   583  1904 W WindowManager:         at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
01-25 12:12:07.408   583  1904 W WindowManager:         at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:540)
01-25 12:12:07.408   583  1904 W WindowManager:         at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.insetsControlChanged(IWindow.java:765)
01-25 12:12:07.408   583  1904 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.notifyInsetsControlChanged(WindowState.java:3582)
01-25 12:12:07.408   583  1904 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.InsetsStateController.lambda$notifyPendingInsetsControlChanged$4$InsetsStateController(InsetsStateController.java:428)
01-25 12:12:07.408   583  1904 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$InsetsStateController$-1iOXDf-1s3wDHcMIHBKNk6MS3I.run(Unknown Source:2)
01-25 12:12:07.408   583  1904 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.executeAfterPrepareSurfacesRunnables(WindowAnimator.java:323)
01-25 12:12:07.408   583  1904 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.performSurfacePlacementNoTrace(RootWindowContainer.java:853)
01-25 12:12:07.408   583  1904 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.performSurfacePlacement(RootWindowContainer.java:801)
01-25 12:12:07.408   583  1904 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacementLoop(WindowSurfacePlacer.java:178)
01-25 12:12:07.408   583  1904 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacement(WindowSurfacePlacer.java:127)
01-25 12:12:07.408   583  1904 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacement(WindowSurfacePlacer.java:116)
01-25 12:12:07.408   583  1904 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.postWindowRemoveCleanupLocked(WindowManagerService.java:1988)
01-25 12:12:07.408   583  1904 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeImmediately(WindowState.java:2122)
01-25 12:12:07.408   583  1904 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeIfPossible(WindowState.java:2241)
01-25 12:12:07.408   583  1904 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.access$300(WindowState.java:249)
01-25 12:12:07.408   583  1904 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:2731)
01-25 12:12:07.408   583  1904 W WindowManager:         at android.os.IBinder$DeathRecipient.binderDied(IBinder.java:305)
01-25 12:12:07.408   583  1904 W WindowManager:         at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(BinderProxy.java:654)
01-25 12:12:07.416   583   933 I ActivityManager: Process com.revolerlife (pid 17214) has died: prcp TOP
01-25 12:12:07.417   583   634 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10169 pid 17214 in 0ms
01-25 12:12:07.420   583   933 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_9 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
01-25 12:12:07.420   583   933 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_7 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
01-25 12:12:07.420   583   933 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_10 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
01-25 12:12:07.420   583   933 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_4 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
01-25 12:12:07.420   583   933 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_6 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
01-25 12:12:07.420   583   933 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_3 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
01-25 12:12:07.420   583   933 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_11 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
01-25 12:12:07.420   583   933 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_5 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
01-25 12:12:07.420   583   933 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_8 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
01-25 12:12:07.420   583   933 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_2 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
01-25 12:12:07.420   583   933 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_9 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
01-25 12:12:07.420   583   933 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_7 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
01-25 12:12:07.420   583   933 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_10 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
01-25 12:12:07.420   583   933 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_4 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
01-25 12:12:07.420   583   933 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_6 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
01-25 12:12:07.420   583   933 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_3 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
01-25 12:12:07.420   583   933 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_11 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
01-25 12:12:07.420   583   933 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_5 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
01-25 12:12:07.420   583   933 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_8 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
01-25 12:12:07.420   583   933 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_2 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
01-25 12:12:07.422   583   626 W ActivityManager: setHasOverlayUi called on unknown pid: 17214
01-25 12:12:07.424   583   624 V OneTimePermissionUserManager: Importance changed for com.revolerlife (10169). importance=1000
01-25 12:12:07.424   583   624 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) android.ui identical 1 line
01-25 12:12:07.425   583   624 V OneTimePermissionUserManager: Importance changed for com.revolerlife (10169). importance=1000
01-25 12:12:07.451   367   433 D goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x8e6200
01-25 12:12:07.451   367   433 D goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3f8754000 size 0x8e8000
01-25 12:12:07.466   583   627 W WindowManager: Failed to deliver inset state change to w=Window{e7ad92a u0 com.revolerlife/com.revolerlife.MainActivity}
01-25 12:12:07.466   583   627 W WindowManager: android.os.DeadObjectException
01-25 12:12:07.466   583   627 W WindowManager:         at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
01-25 12:12:07.466   583   627 W WindowManager:         at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:540)
01-25 12:12:07.466   583   627 W WindowManager:         at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.insetsControlChanged(IWindow.java:765)
01-25 12:12:07.466   583   627 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.notifyInsetsControlChanged(WindowState.java:3582)
01-25 12:12:07.466   583   627 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.InsetsStateController.lambda$notifyPendingInsetsControlChanged$4$InsetsStateController(InsetsStateController.java:428)
01-25 12:12:07.466   583   627 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$InsetsStateController$-1iOXDf-1s3wDHcMIHBKNk6MS3I.run(Unknown Source:2)
01-25 12:12:07.466   583   627 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.executeAfterPrepareSurfacesRunnables(WindowAnimator.java:323)
01-25 12:12:07.466   583   627 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animate(WindowAnimator.java:204)
01-25 12:12:07.466   583   627 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.lambda$new$1$WindowAnimator(WindowAnimator.java:100)
01-25 12:12:07.466   583   627 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$WindowAnimator$ddXU8gK8rmDqri0OZVMNa3Y4GHk.doFrame(Unknown Source:2)
01-25 12:12:07.466   583   627 W WindowManager:         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:970)
01-25 12:12:07.466   583   627 W WindowManager:         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
01-25 12:12:07.466   583   627 W WindowManager:         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:727)
01-25 12:12:07.466   583   627 W WindowManager:         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
01-25 12:12:07.466   583   627 W WindowManager:         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
01-25 12:12:07.466   583   627 W WindowManager:         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-25 12:12:07.466   583   627 W WindowManager:         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
01-25 12:12:07.466   583   627 W WindowManager:         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
01-25 12:12:07.466   583   627 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
01-25 12:12:07.471   367   367 D goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x8e6200
01-25 12:12:07.471   367   367 D goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3fd378000 size 0x8e8000
01-25 12:12:07.491   367   367 D goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x8e6200
01-25 12:12:07.491   367   367 D goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3fca90000 size 0x8e8000
01-25 12:12:07.509   367   433 D goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x8e6200
01-25 12:12:07.509   367   433 D goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3fb67d000 size 0x8e8000
01-25 12:12:07.550   367  6067 D goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x8e6200
01-25 12:12:07.550   367  6067 D goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3fad95000 size 0x8e8000
01-25 12:12:07.551  8217 17116 E sb.v.u.LiteSuggestSourc: On-device lite suggest model loading error.
01-25 12:12:07.560  8217  8283 W ThreadPoolDumper: Queue length for executor EventBus is now 11. Perhaps some tasks are too long, or the pool is too small.
01-25 12:12:07.567  8217  8276 W LocationOracle: No location history returned by ContextManager
01-25 12:12:07.591   367   433 D goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x8e6200
01-25 12:12:07.592   367   433 D goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3fa4ad000 size 0x8e8000
01-25 12:12:07.605  1474  1474 I ShortcutsDataManager: AbstractContentDataManager.startImportContentTask():208 startImportContentTask()
01-25 12:12:07.608  8217  8217 I BgTaskExecutorImpl: Starting EXCLUSIVE background task TNG_MINUS_ONE_SYNC.
01-25 12:12:07.609  1474  2116 I ShortcutsDataManager: AbstractContentDataManager$ImportContentTask.doInBackground():222 doInBackground()
01-25 12:12:07.609  1474  2116 I PersonalDictionaryDataHandler: PersonalDictionaryDataHandler.beginProcess():111 LanguageTags = [en-US]
01-25 12:12:07.620  8217  8283 I TngMinusOneSync: Syncing TNG:-1
01-25 12:12:07.630  1474  2116 I ShortcutsDataManager: AbstractContentDataManager.importRecords():312 importRecords() : Success : Count = 0
01-25 12:12:07.636  1474  2116 I ShortcutsDataManager: AbstractContentDataManager.importContentData():262 importContentData() : Ending import process
01-25 12:12:07.655  1474  2116 I PersonalLanguageModelUpdater: PersonalLanguageModelUpdater$UpdateOperation.performInternal():160 run() : Added 0 words and 0 shortcuts
01-25 12:12:07.655  1474  2116 I DynamicLanguageModelOperation: DynamicLanguageModelOperation.perform():37 perform() : 4 : coc : Completed
01-25 12:12:07.655  1474  3044 I Delight5Decoder: Delight5DecoderWrapper.loadLanguageModel():578 loadLanguageModel() : 4, version [n/a]
01-25 12:12:07.655  1474  3044 I Delight5Decoder: Delight5DecoderWrapper.loadLanguageModel():616 Loaded dynamic LM 4.en
01-25 12:12:07.656  1474  1474 I ShortcutsDataManager: AbstractContentDataManager$ImportContentTask.onPostExecute():233 onPostExecute() : Result = [2,0]
01-25 12:12:07.656  1474  1474 I ShortcutsDataManager: ShortcutsDataManager.onImportFinished():99 onImportFinished() : Result = 2 : Count = 0
01-25 12:12:07.614   583   627 W WindowManager: Failed to deliver inset state change to w=Window{e7ad92a u0 com.revolerlife/com.revolerlife.MainActivity}
01-25 12:12:07.614   583   627 W WindowManager: android.os.DeadObjectException
01-25 12:12:07.614   583   627 W WindowManager:         at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
01-25 12:12:07.614   583   627 W WindowManager:         at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:540)
01-25 12:12:07.614   583   627 W WindowManager:         at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.insetsControlChanged(IWindow.java:765)
01-25 12:12:07.614   583   627 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.notifyInsetsControlChanged(WindowState.java:3582)
01-25 12:12:07.614   583   627 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.InsetsStateController.lambda$notifyPendingInsetsControlChanged$4$InsetsStateController(InsetsStateController.java:428)
01-25 12:12:07.614   583   627 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$InsetsStateController$-1iOXDf-1s3wDHcMIHBKNk6MS3I.run(Unknown Source:2)
01-25 12:12:07.614   583   627 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.executeAfterPrepareSurfacesRunnables(WindowAnimator.java:323)
01-25 12:12:07.614   583   627 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animate(WindowAnimator.java:204)
01-25 12:12:07.614   583   627 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.lambda$new$1$WindowAnimator(WindowAnimator.java:100)
01-25 12:12:07.614   583   627 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$WindowAnimator$ddXU8gK8rmDqri0OZVMNa3Y4GHk.doFrame(Unknown Source:2)
01-25 12:12:07.614   583   627 W WindowManager:         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:970)
01-25 12:12:07.614   583   627 W WindowManager:         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
01-25 12:12:07.614   583   627 W WindowManager:         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:727)
01-25 12:12:07.614   583   627 W WindowManager:         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
01-25 12:12:07.614   583   627 W WindowManager:         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
01-25 12:12:07.614   583   627 W WindowManager:         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-25 12:12:07.614   583   627 W WindowManager:         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
01-25 12:12:07.614   583   627 W WindowManager:         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
01-25 12:12:07.614   583   627 W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
01-25 12:12:09.393   583   632 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
01-25 12:12:09.393   583   632 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
01-25 12:12:10.178 27970 27986 W audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 78769044 , only wrote 78631899
01-25 12:12:10.182   583   928 I system_server: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is facing a similar problem in future. I would suggest taking a keen look at the affected screen for any irregularities. For instance, I faced the same issue with a project that had updated React Navigation from v4 to v6, some of the prop names were changed in V6 and while this did not cause an issue on the dev build, it definitely caused a crash on the specific screens that were still using the old props names. After updating the props the release build is now working fine.